# Windows 10 Pro Game DVR not recording Microphone

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, recording

It used to work than some Microsoft updates later it stopped working. I don't often try to record my microphone so I am not sure when.

I have verified my Windows 10 Game DVR Settings

- Record audio when I record a game: On
- Turn mic on by default when I record: Checked
- Record game audio only: Off
- Recorded Video: 60 fps
- Video quality: High
- Capture mouse cursor in recordings: Checked

Additionally, I checked the Microphone Privacy Settings

- Allow apps to access your microphone: On
- Choose which apps can access your microphone: All On except Cortana and Win32WebViewHost (default settings). I tried turning these on but didn't help.

In case it matters, I am using Sony PlayStation Gold Wireless Headset (https://smile.amazon.com/PlayStation-Gold-Wireless-Headset-Uncharted-Limited/dp/B01BEELH70). I know the Microphone is working because people I am playing with can hear me just fine. The only issue is Game DVR isn't recording my voice when it is recording both game audio and other player voices.

Any help resolving this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I need to set Record game audio only to On for it to start recording microphone audio.

It doesn't make sense and feels like Microsoft people creating these settings and making these changes aren't using their own product.